# How to copy hyperlink addresses using the keyboard

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

I would like to copy the address of a hyperlink in *Mathematica* using the keyboard.
I found code for copying hyperlink addresses in `ContextMenus.tr`:

```
MenuItem["&Copy Address", FrontEndExecute[
 {FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard[
  CurrentValue[{ButtonBoxOptions, ButtonData}]]]
 }
], MenuEvaluator->None]
```

but using this to make a keyboard shortcut in KeyEventTranslations.tr as follows doesn't seem to work.

```
Item[KeyEvent["c", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}], FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard[ CurrentValue[{ButtonBoxOptions, ButtonData}]]]
]
```

(`KeyEvent["c", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}]` didn't seem to work at all as a shortcut combination, but other combinations that worked for other actions didn't work for copying the hyperlink address.)
One problem is that I'm not sure whether the hyperlink has to be selected or what.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand what you want to do: Could you explain  why you don't select that link and press Ctrl+c and then Ctrl+v?

Comment: Well, there's more than way of inserting a hyperlink into some text.  For example, one can create a hyperlink with `Hyperlink` and then copy and paste it into the text, or one can select some text and create a hyperlink using the menu.  In those two cases, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v either copies a large `TagBox` expression or just the text of the hyperlink, not the address (URI).  I now see that one possible solution might be to copy the `TagBox` expression and then use another program to replace the clipboard contents with the hyperlink address, which is inside the expression.

Comment: It's possible, if one has no other option, to Show Expression (Ctrl+Shift+e) and copy the address from there.

Comment: I notice that in your `MenuItem` you write ``FEPrivate`FronEndExecute`` while in the `KeyEvent` you just write `FrontEndExecute`. Maybe that difference is why the menu item works, but the keyboard shortcut doesn't?

Comment: @celtschk I don't think so.  The right-click code knows what was right-clicked, but I'm not sure how the keyboard-shortcut code would.

Comment: The code doesn't work for two reasons. One is that this is not quite the code that is used in the context menu, and the mistranslation here mixes things running in the FE's packet system (``FrontEnd`CopyToClipboard``) with things which don't run in the packet system (`CurrentValue`). That would be trivial to work around, but there's a deeper problem, which is that `CurrentValue` will only return the correct thing if *exactly* the right thing is selected.  It works in context menus because the menu system automatically sets the right target.  I'm still pondering alternative solutions.

Comment: @JohnFultz did you ever think of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

#### What will trigger it

select a hyperlink and use a shortcut, in case of wrong selection you will get `Beep[]`

#### What will happen

```
If[
   MatchQ[#, {_}], 
   CopyToClipboard[First[#]], 
   Beep[]
] &[
     Cases[
        CurrentValue["SelectionData"], 
        _[ButtonData, {x_, _}] :> x, 
        Infinity
     ]
]
```

#### How to implement it

1. With joker.m from the `` Shortcuts` `` package

   Analogous steps like in [**Wrapping highlighted text in chosen brackets. Is there no keyboard command for this?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72914/5478)
2. The second solution is your initial approach, editing `KeyEventTranslations.tr`

   At the moment of loading those files the *FrontEnd* doesn't know `@:>_` and all other fancy syntactic features. So we have to put there crude expressions:

```
 Item[  
    KeyEvent["r", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    KernelExecute[ 
        Function[
            If[
                MatchQ[Slot[1], List[Blank[]]], 
                CopyToClipboard[First[Slot[1]]], 
                Beep[]
            ]
        ][
        Cases[
            CurrentValue["SelectionData"], 
            RuleDelayed[
               Blank[][ButtonData, List[Pattern[x, Blank[]], Blank[]]],  
               x
            ],
            Infinity
        ]]      
    ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
],
```

This works well.

3. Short 2.

   Or just put there

   ```
    KernelExecute[ Needs["MyShortcuts`"]; MyShortcuts`CopyAdress[] ]
   ```

   after saving `MyShortcuts.m` with this definition somewhere on `$Path`.

   `` Shortcuts` `` package uses this approach.