# Create custom shortcut to change font color

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

Just wondering if I can create a custom shortcut key to change the font color of the notebook text.

I've created a custom shortcut (in dkyeventtransactions.tr) to bring up the font color dialog, as so...

```
Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control}],  
     FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["FontColorDialog"]]]
```

but I'm hoping to create different shortcut keys to change the font directly to different colors, without using the font color selection dialog.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, this is very close, but it seems to have the effect of coloring all the characters in the line before the spot that I use it, rather than just change the color for the characters I type next.  I your example below, if I were to use the press [Ctrl]-t after typeing dsf, it will change the dsf to red also.

Answer (score 8):

You have to add the following statement to the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file:

```
Item[KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Control}],
     FrontEndExecute[
      FrontEnd`SetOptions[ 
                 FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[ FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]], 
                 FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]]]
```

> [image]

Be careful: there are not many "free" letters available and when you use one that is already in use, it will not work :)

---

p.s. a more flexible solution is available with Shortcuts package and *joker* functionality, just proceed like in: [**72914**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72914/5478)

Comment: How does one use this using the _joker_ functionality? I tried including   `NotebookApply[SelectedNotebook[], FrontEndExecute[
      FrontEnd`SetOptions[ 
                 FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[ FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]], 
                 FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]], Before]` in the joker file, but this is wrong as it produces Null (as well as switching to a red font). What is my mistake?

It also does not switch the font to red if the selection is not currently on a new line, but this is a minor issue.

Comment: @Kvothe put `SetOptions[   NotebookSelection[ InputNotebook[]],                  FontColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]`, that should be enough

Answer (score 7):

One can change

```
MenuItem["Red",     FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]],
```

to, e. g.,

```
MenuItem["Red",     FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0], MenuKey["r", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

in the **MenuSetup.tr** file.

> [image: example]

This has the additional advantage of adding the shortcuts to the menu for easier lookup.

[image: menu]

Comment: Where is one supposed to make the suggested change?

Comment: `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "Windows"}` (make sure to save a copy before editing), see also [How do I add new menuitems to menus?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/907/how-do-i-add-new-menuitems-to-menus)

Comment: To avoid messing with the $InstallationDirectory, copy `MenuSetup.tr` to `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd",
"TextResources", "Windows"}` and edit there. You may need to manually create some of those folders. Should take precedence over the other `MenuSetup.tr` file.