# Shortcut key to extend selection in the same way as mouse multiclicks

Tags: notebooks, keyboard

I would like to make a key-binding to select everything below one level above my the current postion of the cursor. This should be the same what happens if I multi-click on an expression -- each click goes one level up. But it would be very comfortable do it on the keyboard.

I have checked the [Keyboard Shortcut Listing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) and [Shortcuts package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85824/2036) by Rolf Mertig, and it seems to me, that such a key-binding is not readily available. There is an example on how to make a key-binding, which would [change color of the select text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/create-custom-shortcut-to-change-font-color) to get started.

There are some more general instructions in these answers:

- [Rebinding keys to define new keyboard shortcuts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7611/rebinding-keys-to-define-new-keyboard-shortcuts)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is what you are looking for. This is the already assigned shortcut for **Edit** > **Extend Selection**

Comment: Thanks. If you know how it is called, it is not so hard to find.

Comment: I was really wondering why no one had asked it before. Now I know. AFK in shame.

Comment: @Johu. Yes, as in fantasy fiction, knowing the true name of something in Mathematica gives you power over it.