# How to add a keyboard shortcut to open a Palette

Tags: front-end

I would like to add a hotkey or keyboard shortcut to open a `Mathematica` Palettte, like e.g. the `Basic Math Assistant`. I found a number of questions like [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68864/41148) or [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47474/41148) with answers suggesting to make changes to the  `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file. But I could not figure out how to apply these ideas to make a shortcut for a general menu command.

The path of the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` can be found with the following command

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources", $OperatingSystem}]
```

For example, on Windows, the file location would be like

`"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.2\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(* Palettes *)
    Item[KeyEvent["x", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}],
        FrontEndExecute[{
            FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[
                "OpenFromPalettesMenu",
                "BasicMathAssistant.nb"
        ]}
    ]],
```

Adding the code above into `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, restart Mathematica, then you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to open BasicMathAssistant.

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/what-is-the-complete-list-of-valid-front-end-tokens) you can find out all the `FrontEndToken` that we can use.

Comment: As I understand it, [`FrontEndTokenExecute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrontEndTokenExecute.html) should save a few keystrokes by combining `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[“name”]]`.

Comment: Right. Maybe that time I just wanted to keep consistent with the original `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file.