# Is it possible to navigate in the frontend by cell merely by keystrokes?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

**What are the keystrokes to**

- go to the next cell? (depending on cell(s) currently selected)
- go to the previous cell? (depending on cell(s) currently selected)
- select the enclosing group of cells? (i.e. up one level)
- select the first cell of the currently selected cell group? (i.e. down one level, further down into the cell if you are on the innermost cell bracket level)
- select the last cell of the currently selected cell group? (i.e. down one level)

I know one might construct such things form SelectionMove, but these functions might already be there and they might already be assigned to keys. (I have no idea how to achieve a key binding programmatically).

Comment: I have never studied this, so there are likely better ways, but what I do is this: move the cursor inbetween two cells. Press shift-up (or shift-down) to select a cell bracket. Now up and down will move cell-by-cel (instead of line by line).  Select enclosing group is possible with `ctrl-.`, i.e. the same as *extend selection* within a cell.

Comment: Do this: [126383](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126383/5478) and then once you have the cell selected you can proceed with arrows and Ctrl+.