# How to increase the scroll speed with the keyboard?

Tags: front-end

When I use ctrl + arrow key  I can go up or down without moving the cursor (works differently on mac see comment below). However, it's slow, are there frontend functions or options to increase the speed?

Comment: What system? On Macs, ctrl + arrow sends you to the beginning/end of the notebook. And arrows alone move one line. I use shift + arrow to select a cell; then arrows scroll a cell at a time and repeat if held down.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am using Linux. The shift plus arrow is nice but then I have to scroll back up and sometimes I get lost in very long notebooks. By using ctrl + arrow I can scroll/(move the screen) without moving the cursor and then return back to where I was by just typing something as the cursor never moved.

Comment: Actually, I can maybe just use ctrl+Z to return to where I was. Thanks.

Comment: In large notebooks I use sections and subsections to segment it. They can be closed, which helps navigation. I can put keywords in their titles (or in comments of long codes), and use Find to navigate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 after reading your comment I went looking for ways to close a group using the keyboard. There is a keyboard shortcut to close a selected group `Ctrl+'`  as shown in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html and the first comment at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136672/86543 shows how to move to the parent enclosing cell group/bracket using `Ctrl+.` (Ctrl+Dot, the same as used for extending an expression in a precedence-aware manner). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just had to check the Keyboard shortcuts page (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) for Scroll Page Down.

Pressing <kbd>PgDn</kbd> is fast enough and on my laptop (linux, fedora, mathematica 13.2) (does not work on mac see comment below post) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> is a bit slower and might provide more control.