# Creating a keyboard shortcut to change the Style of text

Tags: evaluation, keyboard, system, configuration

I'm editing a very long text in a Mathematica notebook and I'm using the "Article" stylesheet. In this text, code is highlighted using

```
Style[codeToHighlight, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSlant -> Italic]
```

or `Format -> Font -> ...` after selecting it.

I want to define a "Ctrl + 0" keyboard shortcut to make selected a portion of text cell appear in Arial + Italic Style.

I'm [re-reading this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/how-can-i-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-a-command) and trying to make sense of what should I put into `MenuSetup.tr`, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach.

Comment: I think this could help. Please refer to the following bit of documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html

Comment: To be able to easy change the procedure I'm recommending using *joker* functionality from ``Shortcuts` `` package: [34159](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34159/5478)

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
DynamicModule[
 {font = "Courier"},
 EventHandler[
  Style["Text", FontFamily -> Dynamic[font]],
  {"KeyDown", 
    "x"} :> (font = 
     font /. {"Times" -> "Courier", "Courier" -> "Times"})]
 ]
```

On press of button `x` text `"Text"`toggles between font `"Times"` and `"Courier"`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do what I want.